# gwt intellij 10 plugin does not generate javascript output

Tags: gwt, intellij-idea

With IntelliJ 10, I can easily create a module with a GWT sample application (MySampleApplication.gwt.xml), using the built-in GWT plugin.
This runs fine in hosted mode and I can step through the Java code.

But, I don't see any build options to have it generate the actual output javascript files that are generated by the gwt compiler (which is of course the point of gwt).

Do I have to fiddle with the ant or maven files myself?  Presumably there must be a way to get this intellij gwt plugin to make the gwt compiler run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GWT compiler is invoked when you build the artifact containing **GWT Compiler output** element. Such artifact is added automatically by IDEA for the new projects created via the wizard.

To build such artifact use **Build | Build 'artifact name' Artifact**. Note that you can configure IDEA to build artifacts on **Build | Make** automatically, but it's not recommended for GWT as it would invoke GWT compiler and take considerable time on every **Make**.

Answer (score 1):

When you setup your GWT project you do not have to check "make" check box, this way it will not compile the code every time you run in hosted mode. This is what hosted mode is all about. You DO NOT NEED to compile the code for hosted mode except when you add a DTO because it is serializable. However, you do need to create an artifact and add that to your web module.